# How many integer numbers between 0 and 9999 are there that have exactly one digit 1 and exactly one digit 3?

Tags: combinatorics

**What do I need to think about this problem?**

> How many integer numbers between 0 and 9999 are there that have exactly one digit 1 and exactly one digit 3?

The only thing I know that the total configurations is $10^4$ so if I want to count the numbers which at least have 1 three firstly I get the numbers which not have three's $9^4$ and then subtract and the same for four but how can I count with more restrictions?

Comment: First chose your spot for the $1$ and the $3$. How many possibilities to chose 2 spots out of 4 (when order matters)? Then how many choices do you have for the other two digits?

Comment: Hint for another method. How many ways are there to place a single $1$ and a single $3$? Then how many ways are there to fill in the other two digits?

Comment: now I understand that there are p(4,2)=12 ways to choose the spot for 3 and 4 but I have no idea about how to choose the rest @PattuX

Comment: You have to make two choices. Each of those can be any digit, except $1$ or $3$, so you're left with 8 choices. That makes $8^2$ possibilities to chose the other two digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position of the digit $1$ can be chosen in $4$ ways, the position of the digit $3$ can be chosen in $3$ ways. The remaining two digits should belong to the set $\{0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ which has $8$ elements.

Hence the number of integers between 0 and 9999 that have exactly one digit 1 and exactly one digit 3 is
$$4\cdot 3\cdot 8\cdot 8=768.$$

Comment: 13XX

31XX

XX13

XX31

1XX3

3XX1

X13X

X31X

Comment: those are the total configurations

Comment: What about 3X1X or 1X3X? There are $4\cdot 3=12$ different configurations.

Comment: I miss it because I don't know the rule i try to see all the possibilities

Comment: You are not following my hint... See also the comments.

Comment: got it but still have no idea about how many ways to choose the other numbers

Comment: do you mean that after the 3 and 4 spots chosen there are 8*8 possibilities for the other numbers

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: thank's a lot sir. what do I need to study for problems like this I mean if I played a little with the problem structure I can get many, like what if we consider the same problem but count only the consecutive three's and one's

Comment: @moustafa soama  On right of this page you will find links to related problems involving counting and digits with restrictions. Try them!

Answer (score 3):

There is no good 1 digit number.

There are only $2$ good 2 digit number.

There are $7\cdot 2\cdot 1+2\cdot 2\cdot 8=46$ good 3 digit numbers.

There are $7\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 8 +2\cdot 3\cdot 8\cdot 8=720$ good 4 digit numbers.

So we have $768$ good numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I get a different answer...while I understand your logic here.

Here is mine:

Suppose $A = \{1,\} B =\{ 3\}, C = \{0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $D = \{0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

In a 4-digit number, we can place: $A-B-C-D$ in $4!$ ways.

Now, we know that there is only 1 way to choose $A$, 1 way to choose $B$, but 8 ways to choose $C$ and 8 ways to choose $D$.

So, by product rule, we have:
$$4! * 1 * 1 * 8 * 8 = 1536$$.

I get $1536 = 2*768$, but I guess it is because of the way I think of it, the order of $C$ and $D$ matters $(=2!)$.

As I understand this problem to be referring to k-permutations (the order of each digit matters), shouldn't the answer be $1536$ and not $768$?

Comment: nvm, 1322 is 1322. So 1536 should be divided by 2

Comment: You have double counted every number, not only the ones where $C=D$. For example you have counted the number $1345$ both as $C=4, D=5$ where the number is $ABCD$ and as $D=4, C=5$ where the number is $ABDC$. P.S. Your post should be a new question, not an answer to this one.